# Recursively compare file contents from two folders, archive if different, then copy

Tags: powershell

I have been asked to put together this utility in a hurry which will compare files in source/destination folders, check if different, and if so, archive the file in destination via renaming and copy the source file over. I dug around some of the commands and looked at things like `Compare-Object -Recursive`, however I'm not sure if this is the correct command. This is my progress so far:

```
get-childitem -recurse $source | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq (Get-ChildItem -recurse $destination)} | Copy-Item -recurse -path "$source\*" -destination $destination -force
```

But I don't think this is correct. Would greatly appreciate being pointed in the right direction here.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example how you can compare with the compare command.

```
$items1 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Recurse
$items2  = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp2 -Recurse
$diffent = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $items1 -DifferenceObject $items2

foreach($item in $diffent){
    $path = $item.InputObject.FullName
    #copy the item with the path in the variable $path
}
```